# How can I import an external file without it being built in the webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am configuring my infrastructure to run an application vue.

I have two folders vue_lab and vue_prod

I want to create a config.js file in the project root and add this file in .gitignore.

Inside this file I'll put the api url.

I need this file not to be built when running npm run build.

I could use .env.production but the problem is that I have two production environments (lab and prod) and I need to have a different env file in each project.

I tried to create a file config.js at the root of the project:

```
export const API_HOST = 'http://www.url.com.br';
```

inside the component I import the file and use the variable:

```
import {API_HOST} from '../config';
```

the problem is that when running the npm run build command the config.js file is built in the webpack and I can not put it in gitignore. How can I import an external file without it being built in the webpack?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern about using `.env` files is supporting multiple environments, you can actually configure which `.env.*` file you want to use, with something like this:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, ./.env.${process.env.ENVIRONMENT})});
```

You probably have to tweak the snippet above a little bit depending on how you configure webpack.